# Do magazines need to be in your inventory to get their respective bonuses?

Tags: fallout-4

As you collect magazines/books/comics in the wastelands, they apparently give you perks for finding them.

Do the books need to remain in my inventory, or can I display them on a shelf in my settlements without penalty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you pick them up the first time you can do whatever you wish with them.  You keep the perk regardless.

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perk_magazines)